# Create batch file to delete matching file type

Tags: batch-file

I'm hoping someone can help me create a batch file to delete files that match a specific file format (tar) in a specified directory and its subdirectories that are older than 60 days BUT also keep a minimum number of matching files(may only have 1 file and if its older than 60 days we'll want to keep it), delete the rest. I found the example below that works for the root directory z:\zzz but it does not search/delete the matching files in its subdirectories. I'm not a developer so the example is cryptic to me.

```
    @echo off
    pushd z:\zzz\
    for %%X in (tar) do (
      set "skip=1"
      for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d /o-d /tw *.%%X') do (
        if defined skip forfiles /d -60 /s /m "%%F" >nul 2>nul && set "skip="
        if not defined skip del "%%F"
       )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

At present your dir command looks like this:

```
dir /b /a-d /o-d /tw *.%%X
```

To get it to search the subdirectories you need to add the  `/s` command and for safety I would change `*.%%X` to `cd%\*.%%X`

After looking at the code again think I can see two other parts of the code that need changing:

1. `for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%F in` needs to be:
       for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%F in As you only want to keep one old backup.
2. `if defined skip forfiles /d -60 /m "%%F" >nul 2>nul && set "skip="`

   Should be :

   ```
   if defined skip forfiles /d -60 /s /m "*.%%X">nul 2>nul && set "skip="
   ```

   So it includes sub directories and searches by the Current File Extension (As the `/s` being added to the `dir` command makes the `%%F` include the path as well as the file name, which was causing the `forfiles` command to not return any results.)

So with all the changes in place it should look something like :

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\backup"
    for %%X in (tar) do (
        set skip="1"
        for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s /a-d /o-d /tw %cd%\*.%%X') do (
            if defined skip forfiles /s /d -60 /m "*.%%X">nul 2>nul && set "skip="
            if not defined skip del %%F
        )
    )
```

I've tested this on my laptop and it seems to work ok now.  If you can try it and let me know how you get on.

Comment: I tried the second option and its not working either. I noticed the "/s" subdirectory switch seems to keep it working at all. I copied 2 older tar files to the root directory and ran the batch file and it did nothing. I removed the switch and it was able to delete the 2 older files. I tried placing the switch immediately after the "dir" command and it didn't work there either

Comment: @rlivermore - Sorry for the delay, I've corrected the code above now that I've had my laptop in front of me to test it. Hopefully it will work ok for you now. :)

Comment: I do appreciate your persistence in trying to help me! Am I missing something, I don't see the corrected code?

Comment: I corrected and expanded the explanation in my previous answer above these comments. If you reread the explication and  try the code at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: Got it, thank you. The adjustments had the following results, deleted all but the latest copy of the matching files in the starting directory z:\zzz and deleted all tar files in all subdirectories. The desired end result of the script is to delete all matching files except for the latest one in the starting directory and all subdirectories, is that possible?